# Variable that has the path to the current ansible-playbook that is executing?

Tags: ansible

Is there an Ansible variable that has the absolute path to the current playbook that is executing?

**Some context:** I'm running/creating an Ansible script against `localhost` to configure a MySQL Docker container and wanting to mount the data volume relative to the Ansible playbook.

For example, let's say I've checkout a repository to `~/branch1/` and then I run `ansible-playbook dev.yml` I was thinking it should save the volume to `~/branch1/.docker_volume/`. If I ran it from `~/branch2` then it should configure the volume to `~/branch2/.docker_volume/`.

Answer (score 281, accepted):

You can use the `playbook_dir` variable.

See the documentation about [special variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#term-playbook_dir).

---

For example, given the file structure:

```
.
├── foo
│   └── bar.txt
└── playbook.yml
```

When running *playbook.yml*, the task:

```yaml
- ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: "(playbook_dir ~ '/foo/bar.txt') is file"
```

Would give:

```yaml
TASK [ansible.builtin.debug] **************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  (playbook_dir ~ '/foo/bar.txt') is file: true
```

Answer (score 65):

There don't seem to be a variable which holds exactly what you want.

However, quoting [the docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#discovering-variables-facts-and-magic-variables):

> Also available, `inventory_dir` is the pathname of the directory holding
> Ansible’s inventory host file, `inventory_file` is the pathname and the
> filename pointing to the Ansible’s inventory host file.

> playbook_dir contains the playbook base directory.

> And finally, `role_path` will return the current role’s pathname (since
> 1.8). This will only work inside a role.

Dependent on your setup, those or the `$ pwd` -based solution might be enough.

Answer (score 4):

There is no build-in variable for this purpose, but you can always find out the playbook's absolute path with "pwd" command, and register its output to a variable.

```
- name: Find out playbook's path
  shell: pwd
  register: playbook_path_output
- debug: var=playbook_path_output.stdout
```

Now the path is available in variable playbook_path_output.stdout

Comment: In this case `pwd` does not return the path of the playbook script. It returns the current directory of the process (normally `ansible-playbook`). The two don't have to be the same and depend on exact way in which ansible was invoked.

Comment: @Cray is correct.  Irregardless, I just wanted to mention that Ansible already prepares this variable for you: `debug: var=ansible_env.PWD` (this gives me the directory from which I executed `ansible-playbook` on my local machine and the home directory on remote servers)

Comment: Alternatively the current directory can be found with: `{{ lookup('env','PWD') }}`

Answer (score 4):

I was using a playbook like this to test my roles locally:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
     - role: .
```

but this stopped working with Ansible v2.2.

I debugged the aforementioned solution of

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Find out playbooks path
      shell: pwd
      register: playbook_path_output
    - debug: var=playbook_path_output.stdout
```

and it produced my home directory and not the "current working directory"

I settled with

```
---
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - role: '{{playbook_dir}}'
```

per the solution above.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there isn't.  In fact the absolute path is a bit meaningless (and potentially confusing) in the context of how Ansible runs. In a nutshell, when you invoke a playbook then for each task Ansible physically copies the module associated with the task to a temporary directory on the target machine and then invokes the module with the necessary parameters.  So the absolute path on the target machine is just a temporary directory that only contains a few temporary files within it, and it doesn't even include the full playbook. Also, knowing a full path of a file on the Ansible server is pretty much useless on a target machine unless you're replicating your entire Ansible directory tree on the targets.

To see all the variables that are defined by Ansible you can simply run [the following command](http://docs.ansible.com/faq.html#how-do-i-see-a-list-of-all-of-the-ansible-variables):

```
$ ansible -m setup hostname
```

What is the reason you think you need to know the absolute path to the playbook?

Comment: Thanks Bruce, I modified my question to elaborate on what I was trying to do.

Comment: The absolute local path is not meaningless at all. For example it could be used to run any local commands and/or query other local files or services which could not be included in the ansible config directly. The mere fact that ansible has the `local_action` module means that there are legitimate use-cases for this.

Comment: your command didn't work for me. This one did: `ansible -m setup -i 127.0.0.1, localhost`

Answer (score 0):

I use in playbook like this,

```
---

- hosts: test-server
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
    - name: Test output
      shell: 'pwd'
      register: command_output
      args:
        chdir: /root/new-folder/  # <<<<<<<<<< there
    - debug:
        var: command_output.stdout_lines
```